# Why do javascript function statements not implicitly return?

Tags: javascript

```
> [1, 3, 'sfjk', undefined, 3434].filter(function(e){e});
[]
> [1, 3, 'sfjk', undefined, 3434].filter(function(e){return e});
[ 1, 3, 'sfjk', 3434 ]
```

I was hoping that an unspecified last statement would be treated as the return value.

Following too many links to code golf stack exchange, I guess.

My question is about the design of the language and why it was chosen that the first function returns `undefined` rather than `e`.

Comment: You would have to ask Brendan Eich.

Comment: I'm not understanding why you think a function should return something without explicitly telling it to return.  .Net has lambda expressions which are a different construct for such things... Maybe I'm missing the boat completely here.. but a function should behave like a function regardless of the way it's being applied..  What am I missing?

Comment: So I don't have to write `return` because it's obvious